# Bootstrap "Header / Jumbotron"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using the following code to create a header "logo" for a webpage:

```
<header>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <!-- insert logo here -->
    </div>
</header>
```

What is typically the best way / resolution to make the image in so that it consistently fits the entire jumbotron, but doesn't distort too much when shrunk to mobile / tablet sizes? Also, once I make the image, and src it where I have "insert logo here" is there CSS I can use to help with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to make the image take up the entire `jumbotron`, then you can apply a class to your `<img>`, like `.image` and use `CSS` to style it as so:

```
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

You will still see a slight background from the `jumbotron` class so I would suggest adding this:

```
.jumbotron {
  padding:0;
}
```

As far as responsiveness, so that you know for any future needs, you can use `@media` to manipulate certain classes or tags for different screen sizes. Example:

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {

    .image {
        width: 75%;
    }
}
```

This means that the width of all `.image` classes will be 75% for any screen size that is less than or equal to `500px`.